# script throws syntax error despite no visible issue

Tags: syntax-error, ti-basic

I am making a little game for my ti 84+ and it works, until it hits this line : OUTPUT(8,F,"    //") (note, it through the error specifically on the comma between f and ") i cant find anything that says that that line is invalid, and i'm new to ti-basic so i don't know if there can be weird bugs with it.  the entire script:

```
PROGRAM:PONG
:7→A:8→B
:DelVar C1→D
:-1→E:6→F
:Repeat C
:If A=1
:-D→D
:E-2Emax({A=7,B>=F,B<=F+3→
:E-2E(B=1 or B=16)→E
:A=8→C
:Output(A,B," //")1 space
:A+D→A
:B+E→B
:Output(A,B,"."
:getKey
:F+(Ans=26)-(Ans=24
:If 15<=Ans
:1
:If 0>=Ans
:13
:Output(8,F,"    //")
:Ans→F
:Output(8,F,"--")
:End
:ClrHome
:Output(1,1,"U LOSE")
```

i have tried reformatting the line multiple times with no luck (ex: removing the spaces, changing the comma for a space etc)

thank you for your time.

Comment: What is `1 space` after that output command intended to mean?

Comment: that appears to be a bug from copying the script, i cant seem to do anything about it.